# Dual partition Linux Mint/OS X. Mint booted fine at first and now fails.

Tags: linux, macos, boot, multi-boot, linux-mint

I'm attempting to dual boot my MacBook Air (1.3 ghz intel core i5) into OS X (v 10.8.5) and Linux Mint ("Quiana", Xfce edition).

I installed rEFInd, rebooted and installed Mint from a USB, and everything was successful. I even rebooted and selected Mint from the boot manager and then played around in it for a while. Everything was working (excepting the wifi, but I already knew those drivers would be missing).

Then I shut down my computer for a few hours, booted back up and chose the Mint partition. The GRUB menu loaded and allowed me to select Mint, but instead of booting it loads a blank screen and I have to force a reboot to get out of it. Trying to boot into Mint Recovery Mode gives this bootup message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mslq0.jpg. I have to force a reboot out of that, too.

I tried completely removing Mint, deleting the Linux partitions, and reinstalling--same problem. A friend suggested that I install gptsync--I did, no change.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Thanks for your consideration,

Alison

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with this as well, unfortunately macbook air graphics cards are notoriously stubborn when it comes to Linux distros, try other distribution and see what works, I was able to dual boot osx and backbox linux after a few hours of trial and error.